# How to position my WebForm where I want it to be *sigh*....?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

Check out how it looks right now:
[image]

How can I make the ContentPlaceHolder go where I outlined? Thanks for the help.

I mainly program in WinForms, so I'm used to just dragging things around. Why can't I do this here. Help me SO!

Edit: Here's what I have in my CSS:

```
.Form
{
    position:absolute;
    left:60px;
}
```

How can I use this on my Form code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/EndUserMasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RegistroNuevoPostulante.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebSite.RegistroNuevoPostulante" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please post the master page markup.

Answer (score 3):

Screw the designer and learn HTML and CSS to understand what's going on.

> I mainly program in WinForms, so I'm used to just dragging things around. Why can't I do this here.

Because the markup engine follows different rules. It's not like you have a screen of pixels and you have a complete control over each.

What you absolutely need to learn is the difference between [Block-level elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block-level_element#Block_elements) and [Inline elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block-level_element#Inline_elements) and the [Box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). Before you understand at least that, it will be difficult to accomplish anything.

Comment: While I appreciate your concern, right now my goal is to hand in this POS project for class. I learn much more on my own, but time is raping me ATM.

Comment: Please post your markup and CSS code for that. Abstract talk is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get your hands dirty. What you expected the designer to do (a Windows Forms like behavior), was formerly called grid layout which was a feature of ASP .NET 1.x. It was removed. As you would expect it only rendered "well" (theoretically) on Internet Explorer.

I recommend you to go through some css tutorials on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/). This [link](http://www.webdesign.org/web/html-and-css/articles/css-for-dummies.5516.html) could be a start point. You'll need to learn a couple of div styling attributes to achieve what you want like float, margin and padding.

You could also try the reverse engineering approach and get a free template from [oswd](http://oswd.org), where I'm sure there's a template that addresses your issue. You could use firefox+firebug to learn how everything was achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish only the simplest of things with the visual designer.  If you actually want to get anything done, you need to get into the source view.

The code you should use will involve something like putting a left margin on the `ContentPlaceHolder`.  This can be accomplished using something like:

```
<div style="margin-left: 200px;">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ... ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Note that this should go in your master page, not your form.

Comment: Put it inside of a div: <div style="margin-left: 200px;"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ... ></div>

Comment: Content Is Not Supported outside script. :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work:

```
    <div id="divX" class="yourCssClass">
        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:Content>
    </div>
```

I don't find any problem in this code and I'm sure you can easily place the child page contents anywhere using the CSS(defining yourCssClass).

**PLEASE NOTE THIS IS THE CODE YOU NEED TO WRITE IN MASTER PAGE.**

Define the CSS class in the master page itself if you want this to be consistent throught out the website or define it in specific pages accordingly. If you don't know CSS, a little bit is below:

```
.yourCssClass
{
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

I guess for the same solution given by "**recursive**", you implemented it on the child page(content webform) due to which you got the error "Content Is Not Supported outside script"! Am I right Papuccino?